# check if less file exists or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering if it is possible to check if a particular less file has called in the header section.
If it is there, I'd like to perform some js action.

Do you know any solution how could I check this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How would you read less from the browser?

Comment: sorry, css, my fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($('head link[href$="yourFileName"]').length) {
    // ... (do your thing)
}
```

But as @LeoJavier suggests, you'd be looking for a `.css` file, not `.less`.

Comment: yes, indeed... Could you explain me the $ sign after href?

Comment: `$=` means _"attribute value ends with ..."_ ([see documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)).

Answer (score 0):

The browser doesn't read less files... it reads the css file generated by the less file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use normal jQuery or javascript selectors to access the link element and then do your logic based on if the href is the path to the file you are referencing.

For example javascript to select the link element and href:

```
var linkElement = document.getElementsByTagName("link");

var linkHref = linkElement.getAttribute("href");
```

Note: I assume you mean CSS file rather than LESS file?

Comment: yes, I!m looking for css file indeed. Thank you for your help!